# What should I do if bad question in first posts review queue has edit pending

Tags: support, review, edits

So recently I was in the "first posts" review queue in Arqade. One of the questions was bad. I would have edited it, except that the edit button was greyed out. Should I wait for it to be edited first then review it or should I click "No action needed" because it should be fixed?

> [image]

Comment: Interesting edge case, in my opinion if post has pending suggested edit it should not appear in the first posts review until the edit is approved/rejected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can safely click "No action needed" - because, in this case, from the "editing" point of view, there's really nothing that you can do, unless you have 2k to approve this edit. (but remember that you can also comment for clarification or some guidance to new users; or maybe you feel like voting on this post or flagging)

If there would be a problem with acting this way on such posts in future (i.e. it would count as incorrect review later), you can post another meta question (maybe linking to this), saying that your action was completely appropriate - because it would be.

Comment: I'm trusting I won't fail any audits.

Comment: @UniversalElectricity You probably won't, since (correct me if I'm wrong) in audits, the edit button is always available. However, when you click it in an audit showing you a bad post, you receive an error message saying "this post has been deleted and can't be edited", therefore revealing that it's an audit. If that happens, just downvote or flag to pass the audit and move on. Anyway, I have never seen an audit where the edit button is grayed out saying that an edit is pending. So if an edit is pending, you can safely click no action needed without being afraid of failing a potential audit.